# Integration Testing in Python

Tags: python, django, testing, integration-testing

We do unit testing, at module level. But in the future we want to do integration testing an project level, too.

*Project*: I use the way django uses the word: A project is a small container for N apps/modules. It contains config, and no code.

Our projects are made of N apps by us, and N apps from external (like south, django-reversion, ...).

How can I structure my modules to run all tests from our apps, but not the one from external apps?

Example: I want to run the tests from our apps "plugin1" and "plugin2", but I don't want to run the tests from south or django-reversion.

**Update**

- The packages are installed in a virtualenv with pip.
- We can't distinguish between external and our apps by directory structure.

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

Comment: @limelights I have read the docs. I don't see a way to automatically distinguish between my apps and external apps.

Comment: @guettli limelights is correct, you can run tests under a specific directory, external apps are not installed under your project directory but rather in your python path, if you run: `./manage.py test ./` it should be sufficient to run test only for your apps.

Comment: @petkostas I updated the question: We can't distinguish between external and our apps by directory structure.